# "One word for "Has the same features""

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a single word to state two versions of a software have the same feature?
I would like to say "Version X+1 is comparable-in-terms-of-features to version X"

I cought "[isofunctional](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isofunctional)" online which seems to be specific to enzymes.

Comment: In this context, "features" effectively means "functionality". The standard term is ***functionally equivalent***.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a native speaker, but I'd try something in the lines of "feature-equivalent".

Comment: As a native speaker, "Version X+1 is feature-equivalent to version X" sounds perfectly lucid.

Answer (score 0):

The word *comparable* means to have a similar feature, or one which does the same thing. You could just use that as you did in your example.

Product X is comparable to product Y.